# Entity Framework foreign key in child object not exposed in model

Tags: linq, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-5

I've been reading enough on the subject from other questions but it doesnt seem like I can find someone a similar setup as mine.

I have a File class, with a HashSet of ShareFileRecipients

```
        public HashSet<SharedFileRecipient> Recipients { get; set; }
```

EF (version 5) maps this perfectly, and that is not the issue, in the database the dbo.SharedFileRecipient table has a foreign key column generated for this relationship "File_Id" which is not exposed in the SharedFileRecipient class.

That was not a problem until yesterday,   I am having to write a query were I am having to join the two (because I desire duplicates for one specific view) but I cannot use LINQ because File_Id is not exposed in SharedFileRecipient.

I tried using the ForeignKey annotation,  the ColumnName annotation

```
    [Column("File_Id")]
    public Guid? File_Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Folder_Id")]
    public Guid? Folder_Id { get; set; }
```

but the application will throw an EF exception, saying that the model has changed. When I ran the Add-Migration to see which changes it "needed" to do, the resulting script was actually trying to get in the database and change the already existing column name from File_Id to File_Id1.

I reverted my changes, I am sure changing the column name like that will do nothing but break the original relationship setup, which works already.

I just really want to be able to use that unexposed File_Id Guid column so I can write my query in LINQ,  that is all.

Answer (score 1):

This blog post explains why what I am trying to do is not available.

> The properties used to map an association—the foreign keys—are not exposed by the Entity Framework and are simply unavailable in the generated code. You can, however, add custom code to your partial classes to expose those values[1]:
>
> return Child.ParentReference.ID; However, you can’t use those
>   properties with LINQ queries because those extra properties cannot be
>   mapped to the database by EF. Without restrictions or orderings on
>   those properties, they’re as good as useless, so we’ll have to work
>   within EF itself.

http://encodo.com/en/blogs.php?entry_id=163